# Showing model using ViewModel

Tags: c#, model, viewmodel

I have a simple client-server application. Server gets data from database, for example I have Product class, that is a representation of database record:

```
class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to show list of products, but I want to show Price + Currency.

I have created:

```
class ProductVM
{
    Product BaseProduct {get; set; }
    public string PriceWithCurrency { get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", BaseProduct.Price, "USD"); } }
}
```

Is it a good way of doing this?
What is the best way to achive my goal?

Comment: Is it always USD? If so then just concatenation on the UI side should do. If not then above should be fine.

Comment: In that case is constant, but I have other properties, for example:
in Product:
List<string> ingredients {get; set; }

in ProductVM:
string IngredientsString { //List of all ingredients in one string }

Answer (score 1):

That's fine with what you have. You can create a list of string as:

```
   public List<string> Ingrediants{ get; } = new List<string>
    {
        "item1",
        "item2"
    }
```